# Código da função bitWrite para usar com microcontrolador PIC

Tags: c, arduino, pic

Estou portanto um código do Arduino para o PIC pro compilador MikroC.
Cheguei em uma parte que contém o seguinte:

```
byte data[3];

// pulse the clock pin 24 times to read the data
for (byte j = 3; j--;) {
    for (char i = 8; i--;) {
        digitalWrite(PD_SCK, HIGH);
        bitWrite(data[j], i, digitalRead(DOUT));
        digitalWrite(PD_SCK, LOW);
    }
}
```

Consegui arrumar ele para:

```
byte data[3];
int j;
int i;

// pulse the clock pin 24 times to read the data
for (j = 3; j--;) {
    for (i = 8; i--;) {
        RD1_bit = 1;
        bitWrite(data[j], i, RD0_bit);
        RD1_bit = 0;
    }
}
```

Assim, falta apenas a função `bitWrite(data[j], i, RD0_bit);` funcionar, porém não cheguei a resultados conclusivos.

Atualmente possuo o seguinte código, que não está rodando:

```
void bitWrite(uint8_t &x, unsigned int n, int b1) {
    if (n <= 7 && n >= 0) {
        if (b1) {
            x |= (1u << n);
        } else {
            x &= ~(1u << n);
        }
    }
}
```

Obs.: Único `include` que estou usando é `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: Não conheço esse compilador nem nunxa usei o  arduino. Do que vi `byte` não é um tipo padrão nem do compilador http://www.mikroe.com/download/eng/documents/compilers/mikroc/pro/pic/help/arithmetic_types.htm nem do `stdint.h`. Agora o mais importante no `bitWrite` parece que estas a passar x como referência, mas isso não existe em C e que variavel é a `1u`?

Comment: @Giovani, o código apresenta algum erro? Este `1u` me parece uma constante de alguma biblioteca do MikroC, pois `x& = ~(1u << n)` é uma máscara de bits e `1u` precisa ter algum valor para isso funcionar.

Comment: @krystalgamer obrigado pelo auxilio, consegui resolver.

Comment: @Avelino obrigado pelo auxilio, consegui resolver.

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini Fiquei curioso para saber o quê este código faz. Gera uma onda quadrada no pino 3? (Ou pino 4 se começa em 0)!?

Comment: @Avelino Gero uma onda quadrada de 24 bits, sendo que cada bit vai representar um bit, pois é um conversor de 24 bits. Para saber mais veja o arquivo HX711.cpp disponível na internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar com o seguinte código:

```
void bitWrite(char *x, char n, char value) {
   if (value)
      *x |= (1 << n);
   else
      *x &= ~(1 << n);
}
```